# Object constructor - managing loop animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, animation

I am doing a website wich has a lot of animations managed by JavaScript, when i started i just defined a function and some variables for the animation and repeat the process, like this. And a think is not the good way.

```
//BRIGHT ANIMATION  
var frameWidth1 = 386;
var frameHeight1 = 100;
var spriteWidth1 = 20067;
var spriteHeight1 = 100;
var spriteElement1 = document.getElementById("bright");

var curPx1 = 0;
var ti1;

function animateSpriteB() {

    spriteElement1.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + curPx1 + 'px 0px';
    curPx1 = curPx1 + frameWidth1;

    if (curPx1 >= spriteWidth1) {
        curPx1 = 0;
    }

    ti1 = setTimeout(animateSpriteB, 70);

}

animateSpriteB();


//  PAPIRO ANIMATION

var frameWidth = 56;
var frameHeight = 218;
var spriteWidth = 2016;
var spriteHeight = 218;
var spriteElement = document.getElementById("roll-off");

var curPx = 0;
var ti;

function animateSprite() {

    spriteElement.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + curPx + 'px 0px';
    curPx = curPx + frameWidth;

    ti = setTimeout(animateSprite, 27.7);

    if (curPx === spriteWidth) {
        clearTimeout(ti);
    }

}

function slideMask(){
    var mask = $("#paper-mask");
    var paper = $("#paper");

    mask.animate({
        width: 450
    },{
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function(){
            $("#paper-content").fadeIn();
        }
    });

}

var ti = setTimeout(function(){
    animateSprite();
    slideMask();
}, 3000);
```

So know, I decided to use a constructor to re use the same code and manage all the animations in the website. i came with Something like this:

```
// CONSTRUCTOR WHO MANAGE THE ANIMATIONS FOR THE WEBSITE
        function SpriteAnimation(frameWidth, spriteWidth, spriteElement, isLoop){
            this.frameWidth = frameWidth;
            this.spriteWidth = spriteWidth;
            this.spriteElement = spriteElement;
            this.isLoop = isLoop;
            this.curPx = 0;
            this.ti;
        }

        SpriteAnimation.prototype.start = function(){

            var selector = document.getElementById(this.spriteElement);

            selector.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + this.curPx + "px 0px";
            this.curPx = this.curPx + this.frameWidth;

            this.ti = setTimeout(this.start, 2000);

            if (this.curPx === this.spriteWidth){
                clearTimeout(this.ti);
            }

            this.start();

        }

        var letter = new SpriteAnimation(935.4, 17774, "letter", true);
        letter.start();
```

I am having problems in performance, every time i run the code my browser just crash i also think im not doing good the loop. So here comes my question: how can i do to manage the animations with an object constructor in wich i can pass parameters like if it is loop animation and the sprite parameters?... I appreciate the help you guys can bring me :)

@Tibos Your code has been from great help for me i just spent almost 4 hours trying to achieve this, and then yo came out and make it really easy, this is how my code looks now, i added another parameter: frame rate. so every animation can have a different frame rate. Also modified a bit the if statement because the animation was running untill the sprite dissapear and i need them to stay in the last frame, let me know if this is the correct form.

```
// CONSTRUCTOR WHO MANAGE THE ANIMATIONS FOR THE WEBSITE
        function SpriteAnimation(frameWidth, spriteWidth, spriteElement, shouldLoop, frameRate){
            this.frameWidth = frameWidth;
            this.spriteWidth = spriteWidth;
            this.selector = document.getElementById(spriteElement);
            this.shouldLoop = shouldLoop ;
            this.curPx = 0;
            this.frameRate = frameRate;
            this.ti;
        }

        SpriteAnimation.prototype.start = function(){

            this.selector.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + this.curPx + "px 0px";
            this.curPx += this.frameWidth;

            if (this.curPx < (this.spriteWidth - this.frameWidth)){
                setTimeout(this.start.bind(this), this.frameRate);
            } else if (this.shouldLoop) {
                this.curPx = 0;
                this.start();
            }

        };

        var letter = new SpriteAnimation(935.4, 17774, "letter", true, 60);
        letter.start();
```

Comment: The problem is that you're calling start again at the end of the start method.

Comment: I think i had to do that to achieve the loop animation, even if i don't call it again the animation doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code, presented here in order of impact:

- recursively calling start
- losing the reference to this
- clearing timeout as soon as it's set
- unused variables
- selecting the element at each iteration

Here is some better code (that works):

```
function SpriteAnimation(frameWidth, spriteWidth, spriteElement, shouldLoop){
    this.frameWidth = frameWidth;
    this.spriteWidth = spriteWidth;
    this.selector = document.getElementById(spriteElement);
    this.curPx = 0;
    this.shouldLoop = shouldLoop;
}

SpriteAnimation.prototype.start = function(){
    this.selector.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + this.curPx + "px 0px";
    this.curPx += this.frameWidth;

    if (this.curPx <= this.spriteWidth){
        setTimeout(this.start.bind(this), 2000);
    } else if (this.shouldLoop) {
        this.curPx = 0;
        this.start();
    }
};

var letter = new SpriteAnimation(935.4, 17774, "letter", true);
letter.start();
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/oJIYoRU/1/edit

Comment: I would like to know why when you call this.start you bin this, i tought this would be referenced always in the object

Comment: The callback passed to setTimeout is called in the global scope. You need to bind it to something if you want to use `this` inside.

Comment: sorry if im a pin in the ass, i am just learning javascript as you can see, if i would like to check  i the animation has to loop or not using the isLoop parameter how i should check for that? ...should i need a method for loope animations and other for non loope?

Comment: just edited my question soy you can see my final code, let me know what do you think

Answer (score 0):

This function calls itself recursively with no base case.  As soon as you invoke it you will lock the UI and overflow the call-stack.

```
SpriteAnimation.prototype.start = function(){
    ... some code ...
    this.start();

}
```

Comment: what do you refer to a base case?